# How to set the height of a row in a datagridview in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a Datagridview that I need to set the row height for I have noticed that the row is currently now being sized based on image that is being displayed in the row.

Comment: thanks, i have tried this and my coloum is still being rezied by my image.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like [`AutoSizeRowsMode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewautosizerowsmode(v=vs.110).aspx) set to none, set it to `AllCells`.

```
dataGridView1.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells;
```

or if you are looking to set size explicitly based on image size, try setting `RowTemplate.Height` before binding.

```
dataGridView1.RowTemplate.Height = 80;
```

Comment: Thanks, I have tried this and it still seems to be getting the size from the image in the row instead of from the settings, any clue as why this would be happening?

Comment: Is it cropping the image or size is adjusting according to image?

Comment: If you are explicitly specifying the height, specify it before binding and also set `AutoSizeRowsMode` to `None`.

Comment: adjusting according to the image everytime i rezise the image the row resizes as well.

Comment: I would suppose so but I am trying to set the row to be bigger height wise than the image.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114243/discussion-between-sheenie-and-hari-prasad).

Comment: If this helps in resolving your problem, and this is the answer to your question., please mark it as an an answer.